# RegEx: How to match second space after every "="

Tags: ruby, regex

I have the following string and I need to split it on the second space after every "=" character. How do I go about writing the regex? I'm working in Ruby.

```
"item1 = 10p item2 = 20p item3 = £1.10 item4 = 25p item5 = £2.94"
```

The goal is to have an array that looks like:

`["item1 = 10p", "item2 = 20p", "item3 = £1.10"]` etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\S+\s*=\s*\S+
```

Its easier to grab the matches instead of split.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/hR7tH4/5

If you still want to split use

```
(?<!=)\s+(?!=)
```

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/hR7tH4/6

Comment: Was just going to ask for the split variant FMI. Thanks for adding!

Answer (score 2):

Using the regular expression that vks suggested, you would use Ruby's `scan` method to create the required array `"string".scan(/regex/)`:

```
irb(main):001:0> "item1 = 10p item2 = 20p item3 = £1.10 item4 = 25p item5 = £2.94".scan(/\S+\s*=\s*\S+/)
=> ["item1 = 10p", "item2 = 20p", "item3 = £1.10", "item4 = 25p", "item5 = £2.94"]
```